# how to pass variable from python app to client javascript on google app engine

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

Does anyone know how to pass data from server code (written in python and run on google app engine) to client javascript?

I know how to do that for php and javascript: In php, make json-formatted variable and I can call the variable in javascript using something like:

```
<script> var data = <?php varname_in_php ?>; </script>
```

How can I achieve the same thing for applications using google app engine ?

I am trying to implement some application which will parses some statistical data using Python, and then pass the data to javascript for plot.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your using webapp2 you could just us the json lib, and do a

`self.request.write(json.dumps(some_data))` in a get handler.

and remember to set your content type to `application/json`

Much simpler than having to use a templating system to just send json.

You client can perform a simple request on the handler.. If your using jquery you would use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ for instance.

Comment: Could you give me some example? Sorry, I am still new to GAE. And can I do 
"self.request.write(json.dumps(some_data))", 

and at the same time send html script by        

template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('macro.html')
self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
?

Comment: Not like that.  If you want a call directly to the handler for dynamic updates you will fetch the data using javascript and then all you need to do is what I have in the answer.  If you just want the data declared as a variable in a HTML page look at the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [templating system](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates).  Django and Jinja2, which are included with Google App Engine, are both straightforward and make this kind of task pretty easy.  Have a look at [this](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) and it should be fairly clear how to do pass variables through `script` tags using Jinja2.

Quick example, assuming you've passed `data` into your Jinja2 template:

```
<script>
var jdata = new Array();
{% for entry in data %}
   jdata.push({{ entry }});
{% endfor %}
</script>
```

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with this answer if all the OP wants is some javascipt with the data definition inserted into the HTML page, especially if they want to replicate the PHP in the original question.